# Exporting Attachments from Evernote using AppleScript

Tags: applescript, evernote

I am having significant issues creating a very simple AppleScript to export attachments from an Evernote note.  I have used the following code several times and it seems to work, but in actuality it fails silently, even though the event log shows a correct response.

I have heard that Evernote's recent versions have significant AppleScript support issues. If someone out there is an Evernote and AppleScript "expert", I would also greatly appreciate a review of my script to make certain I'm not forgetting anything.

I am using Mac OS X 10.8.2 and the Mac App Store version of Evernote 5.0.5 (400805).

Code:

```
set ExportPath to "LegatusHD1:Users:me:Downloads:Test"
set theAttachments to {}
set selectedItems to {}

tell application "Evernote"
set selectedItems to selection
repeat with selectedItem in selectedItems
    set theAttachments to (attachments of selectedItem)
    repeat with theAttachment in theAttachments
        set theFilename to (ExportPath & ":" & theAttachment's filename)
        write theAttachment to theFilename
        set theFilename to ""
    end repeat
end repeat
end tell
```

Comment: The code seems to work for me ...

Comment: @adayzdone:  Which version of Evernote and Mac OS X are you using?  Are they the same as mine?  Are you using Mac OS X 10.8.2 and Evernote 5.0.5 (400805)?

Comment: 10.6.8 and Version 5.0.5 (400808)

Answer (score 0):

Apple has introduced sandboxing for apps from the AppStore recently. So depending on your OSX version, this might be the reason why it fails silently - since the Evernote app is not able to access the file system outside its own folder structure. You can try setting the export path to be something within the Evernote folder.

Comment: That was a good suggestion, however, I downloaded the version from Evernote.com a couple of days ago just to test that theory.  The same problem remains.  I'm really starting to think that Evernote's applescript implementation is very flaky.  I've not seen this many applescript issues with Outlook or Omnifocus, so it seems to be an Evernote issue.

Answer (score 0):

This question is old but I just tripped over it looking for an answer which I can now provide:

FYI I am running: OSX 10.9.1 (Mavericks) and Evernote 5.4.4 installed via App Store.

I can confirm that Mustafa was right, using the App Store version of the app it is only possible to write to files within the sandbox (/Users/{username}/Library/Containers/com.evernote.Evernote/)

## Short answer

Either install the app from the Evernote website or if you want to use the one in the App Store:

Using the above script change the export path to something inside the sandbox e.g.:

```
set ExportPath to "Users:{username}:Library:Containers:com.evernote.Evernote:Data:attachment_export"
```

Remember to make the attachment_export folder first, and replace the {username} with your username

## A note on debugging

Unfortunately applescript editor doesn't show any errors when you try to write outside the sandbox. You can however view the error in the Console application (found in Applications -> Utilities). In Console enter 'sandbox' in the search box (top right hand corner) and at the bottom of the window you will see something like this:

> 1/29/14 10:22:29.426 sandboxd[310]: ([4433]) Evernote(4433) deny file-write-create /Users/{username}/Desktop/Evernote Snapshot 20140128 134741.jpg